# How to use software flow control when writing to a serial port

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am using MATLAB to write values to a serial port where I know that the device receiving the data has a limited input buffer (say 512B).

Currently, the device I am connected to has implemented software flow control, so that it will send `XOFF` (ASCII 0x13) when I should stop sending data, and it will send `XON` (ASCII 0x11) when it is ready to receive data again.

I would like to be able to write values to the serial port without overflowing the buffer on the other end. Suppose that I would like to write 100kB over the serial port.

Unfortunately, setting the `FlowControl` property of the `serial` object to `'software'` seems to have no effect. When I write my data, the input buffer on the device overflows. Additionally, I can see a large number of `XON` and `XOFF` characters in the input buffer of the serial object.

The [Matlab Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-control-pins.html#f85421), is lacking in this regard. It only mentions how to handle software flow control when reading large amounts of data. Also, the way that it is written makes it seem that all the control is manual anyway. What is the difference in setting the `FlowControl` property on a `serial` object to `software` vs. setting it to `none`?

I've tried to hack together my own software handshaking as follows:

```
function write_lots_of_data(serial, string)
    % only write 128B at a time so the buffer does not overflow
    WRITE_SIZE = 128;
    nData = numel(string);
    isReady = is_serial_ready(serial, true);
    for iStart = 1:WRITE_SIZE:nData
        while ~isReady
            isReady = is_serial_ready(serial, isReady);
        end
        iEnd = min(iStart+WRITE_SIZE-1, nData);
        fprintf(serial, '%s', data(iStart:iEnd));
        isReady = is_serial_ready(serial, isReady);
    end
end


function tf = is_serial_ready(serial, tf)
    if serial.BytesAvailable
        input = fread(serial, serial.BytesAvailable);
        % get the last XON or XOFF character
        c = response(find(response == 17 | response == 19, 1, 'last'));
        % only change the output if you actually found one
        if ~isempty(c)
            tf = c == 17;
        end
    end
end
```

This solution is pretty inefficient, and is not bulletproof. I thought that the `MATLAB` serial object would have the handshaking implemented at a low level. Am I missing something? If not, is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Flowcontrol should be implemented by the OS, e.g. in Linux it's the line discipline handler of the tty subsystem.  Of course flowcontrol requires that you use blocking system calls, otherwise you could overrun your local system buffer instead of the remote's buffer.

Comment: I see, so if MATLAB keeps writing to the buffer even when the serial port has received an XOFF character, then it is not a problem with MATLAB? Is there a way to enable this in the OS? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I know nothing about Win7 internals.  *"then it is not a problem with MATLAB?"* -- Not necessarily.  As I previously wrote, the app would have to use blocking syscalls.